# Get Mysql group by and count result in a different format

Tags: mysql

I need to get the count for each status. So I use group by status column and get the below result

```
+------------------+
|  Status  | count |
+------------------+
|  created |   2   | 
+------------------+
| verified |   1   | 
+------------------+
```

I would like to know if I can get the result in a single row as

```
+ ------------------+
| created | verified| 
+-------------------+
| 2       |   1     |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can do

```
SELECT sum(status = 'created') as created,
       sum(status = 'verified') as verified
FROM your_table
```

For all other DB engines use

```
SELECT sum(case when status = 'created' then 1 else 0 end) as created,
       sum(case when status = 'verified' then 1 else 0 end) as verified
FROM your_table
```